# Read path project and load layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, path

How can I correctly concatenate the path of a project with a specific shapefile layer and to be able to load it; this is:

```
QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")   <---path

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(   path   +  capa x "ogr" ) <--example visual

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") "COB.shp", "COB", "ogr")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`absolutePath` method of `QgsProject` gives you folder in where the project is. When concatenating folder and file name, you can use `os.path.join` to get rid of OS differences.

```py
import os

project_path = QgsProject.instance().absolutePath()
shapefile_path = os.path.join(project_path, "COB.shp")
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(shapefile_path, "COB", "ogr")
```